# Home page that changes after logging in made without any cms

Tags: css, html

I want to make a website with register and log in options without any CMS, pure HTML/CSS/whateverelseisneeded. Now what confuses me is how in the blazes do I make one home page that will show for any visitor, with info that would be relevant to the said person?

After logging in however, the page would have an added content that's relevant to the registered person. How do I do this? I can make the webpages but how do I link them? What do I use? I've looked it up on google but couldn't find anything conclusive because I'm not asking the right question. If any of you could tell me what to look for or what to ask I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Sorry, but this type of question is not allowed. Please read the help section on how to ask a question.

Comment: You're basically asking "how to make a website" but unfortunately that's way too broad to be a good question here. Google should find you literally thousands of guides.

Comment: For some direction, HTML/CSS/whateverelseisneeded, whateverelseisneeded could be any server side language like php/node.js/ASP.net for example.

Comment: You need to tell us what you want to use other than html/css, then try something and show us some code.  You can do anything with anything, but I doubt you'd be satisfied with that.

Comment: [](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview)

Comment: If you wish to go with asp.net the link I gave is a good place to start. I recommend asp.net partly because it's what I use and partly because I found it relatively easy to learn. Couldn't get on with php myself but other people I know would highly recommend it as an easy to learn server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning:

A server, as we commonly call it, is a computer which answers queries from other computers. A web server is a computer which answers to specific queries, made using the `http` protocol.

A static web site is when a page does not change. The software simply returns HTML/CSS/any thing the client asks.

What you want to do is called a dynamic web site: the returned value depends on the current state of the server and the query made. For example, when you want to see a Facebook profile, the Facebook web server always returns the same page, only with some changes, because you asked him x profile page.

Dynamic web sites require code to be executed by the server: we call this the back-end. PHP, Go, Ruby, Python are the most commonly used languages by webservers.

I personally use PHP, so I would tend to recommend PHP for beginners who want to create websites quickly, but the best advice I can give you: try, and see. Everyone is different, you may enjoy writing a dynamic web site in Go but hate PHP. Don't use one because your friend told you it is the best language ever. Every programmer will like a language more than others and will try to bring you to their sides.

One last thing: I would not recommend starting web development with an asynchronous language. Linear programming languages are easier, in my opinion, to *start* with. (I know most linear PL can do async, and the other way round, but most languages are adapted to one, or the other, depending on the views of the creators.)

Good luck in the massive world which is web development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get it a bit better now. I'll start researching dynamic websites then. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: No problem. Updated my answer to talk about async PLs.